# Create a menu block based on path using views

Tags: routes, views

I'm trying to use views 3 to create a view that I can place in a block that is based on the url path

For example

example.com/student/
example.com/student/page1
example.com/student/page2
example.com/student/page3

All 4 pages are in the menu along with other pages
Students
   page1
   page2
   page3

I want to create a view that will display (dynamically) on pages with the following url pattern example.com/student/*
I want the view to only return child menu items that have Student as a parent.

I'm working with menu view, but I can not get the contextual filter and relationship to work correctly.  Any tips. Or an alternate way to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [Menu Block](https://drupal.org/project/menu_block) module to accomplish this task. If you want to display a block on specific pages just goto the relevant block configuration and under " Show block on specific pages" select "Only on listed pages" define the following

student/*

Now your block will appear only if this URL pattern will match. No matter what you have used to create your block.

Comment: Right, but then I will have to create a block for every url type. Correct??  One for */student/* another for courses/* etc... and I'll need distinct menus for each group of pages? I would like to be able to do it dynamically based on the sub section of the main menu.